# Casting a Web Control taken from a GridView cell in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagrid

When I have many controls on a Form (i.e. Label, Button etc) that do almost the same thing, I often use one method to handle all the controls Click,

But to know which of the controls throwing the event and access the properties of that control I need to cast the "sender" object to the correct type.

in datagridview :

i want to get the text from a button in a cell in datagridview 
i try this but it's not wotking :s :s

```
Dim btnGrid As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
        btnGrid.HeaderText = "Modifier les lieu"
        btnGrid.Text = "Mise a jour"
        btnGrid.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnGrid)

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            index = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value
            Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, DataGridViewButtonColumn)
            MsgBox(btn.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: @Alain  i want to get the text from a button in a cell in datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim button As DataGridViewButtonCell = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewButtonCell)
MessageBox.Show(button.Value)
```

Comment: tnks dudde this is it .. but a little note ther is no text in a button we can only use the value that be couse we use this 
btnGrid.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True

Comment: @Yassineedouiri.  I just noticed that I wrote that myself.  Thanks.  I corrected my answer.